# Is it possible to copy build artifact from pipeline into repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build

**Disclaimer: This is usually not a good idea, it's far better to use [Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)!**

I'm trying to copy my published zip build into my azure repo for easy access. I have the following YML code. See inline comment with my question:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MyFolder'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\zipfolder/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\zipfolder'
    TargetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyFolder' // Here I would expect the code to copy the zip into my repo.
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Generally speaking source code repositories are for… well… *source code* - not build artifacts and the like.

Comment: We had this idea that it would be easier to access the build artifact in the repo rather than navigating to the built artifact the normal way. It's a temporary solution until we implement CD. We're aware that it might not be best-practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the artifact and use the git command in command line task to push it to the repo, refer to the sample as below, it works for me.

```
# 'Allow scripts to access the OAuth token' was selected in pipeline.  Add the following YAML to any steps requiring access:
#       env:
#           MY_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
# Variable Group 'vargroup1' was defined in the Variables tab
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/testb2
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: True
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive README.md
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: README.md
      archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\zipfolder/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\zipfolder
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Download Build Artifacts
    inputs:
      artifactName: drop
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Command Line Script
    inputs:
      script: >-
        cd $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\zipfolder

        git config --global user.email "xxxxx"

        git config --global user.name "xxxxx"

        git init

        git add .

        git commit -m "123"

        git remote add origin https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/orgname/testpro1/_git/testpro4

        git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/orgname/testpro1/_git/testpro4
...
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to push to repo and then sync from the remote git/ - basically a automated way of pulling the file over.